# Смена пользователя root в ssh с настройками PermitRootLogin в Centos 6

Tags: centos, ssh, root, centos6

Если прописать в настройках ssh:

> vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
>
> PermitRootLogin no

Можно ли залогиниться в систему как root, но уже от другого имени с группы wheel, например *"AdminVasia"*, после того как я уже вошел от имени *"AdminVasia"* с помощью команды ***su root***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

содержимое файла `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` прочитывается при (ре-)старте и принимается к руководству программой *sshd*, той самой, что слушает (по умолчанию) 22-й порт и позволяет подключиться к компьютеру по протоколу [*ssh*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH).

директива `permitrootlogin` со значением `no` в этом файле указывает программе, что подключения к этому компьютеру (по протоколу *ssh*), в которых указан пользователь `root` (типа `ssh root@компьютер`), **не будут приниматься**, даже если указан правильный пароль пользователя `root` (при аутентификации по паролю) или (при аутентификации по ключу) предъявлен правильный секретный ключ, публичная часть которого упомянута в файле `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

к работе программы *su* (да и вообще любой другой помимо *sshd*) ни данный файл вообще, ни данная директива в частности, никакого отношения не имеют.

также данная директива не имеет никакого отношения ни к группе `wheel` (независимо от того, включен ли в неё пользователь `root`, или нет), ни к какой-либо другой группе пользователей этого компьютера.

---

доп. чтение: [`$ man sshd_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config)

Comment: Спасибо, проверил, все работает ;-)